# Custom jQuery code loaded but not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement some custom jquery code for a 3D menu on my Drupal 7 site. I created two .js files one with the code and other one calling it on page. I have succesfully loaded both .js files throug my theme's .info file, however nothing happens, even tho i know the js code is 100% correct and working as it should. Im also using jQuery update module set to 1.8 so that shouldn't be a problem. As i am less than a begginer regarding jquery, i ask for your help. I can't understand why is code being loaded but not working. Thanks for reading and all the answers.

```
(function ($) {

   var Menu = (function() {

    var $container = $( '#rm-container' ),                      
        $cover = $container.find( 'div.rm-cover' ),
        $middle = $container.find( 'div.rm-middle' ),
        $right = $container.find( 'div.rm-right' ),
        $open = $cover.find('a.rm-button-open'),
        $close = $right.find('span.rm-close'),
        $details = $container.find( 'a.rm-viewdetails' ),

        init = function() {

            initEvents();

        },
        initEvents = function() {

            $open.on( 'click', function( event ) {

                openMenu();
                return false;

            } );

            $close.on( 'click', function( event ) {

                closeMenu();
                return false;

            } );

            $details.on( 'click', function( event ) {

                $container.removeClass( 'rm-in' ).children( 'div.rm-modal' ).remove();
                viewDetails( $( this ) );
                return false;

            } );

        },
        openMenu = function() {

            $container.addClass( 'rm-open' );

        },
        closeMenu = function() {

            $container.removeClass( 'rm-open rm-nodelay rm-in' );

        },
        viewDetails = function( recipe ) {

            var title = recipe.text(),
                img = recipe.data( 'thumb' ),
                description = recipe.parent().next().text(),
                url = recipe.attr( 'href' );

            var $modal = $( '<div class="rm-modal"><div class="rm-thumb" style="background-image: url(' + img + ')"></div><h5>' + title + '</h5><p>' + description + '</p><a href="' + url + '">See the recipe</a><span class="rm-close-modal">x</span></div>' );

            $modal.appendTo( $container );

            var h = $modal.outerHeight( true );
            $modal.css( 'margin-top', -h / 2 );

            setTimeout( function() {

                $container.addClass( 'rm-in rm-nodelay' );

                $modal.find( 'span.rm-close-modal' ).on( 'click', function() {

                    $container.removeClass( 'rm-in' );

                } );

            }, 0 );

        };

    return { init : init };

})();
 })(jQuery);
```

And here's the content of other JS file which is calling the function.

```
(function ($) {

$(function() {
Menu.init();
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please define "not working". Also, have you read about [Behaviors](https://drupal.org/node/171213#behaviors)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you to wrap your code in `document.ready` function as below:

```
// Jquery wrapper for drupal to avoid conflicts between libraries.
(function ($) {
  // Jquery onload function.
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Your JS code.
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**Update:** If you declare a variable without the `var` keyword, that variable is automatically made `global`. Aslo you can check more about the scope of the variable here: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/

Comment: So if i understood correctly, you are saying to join two separate js files which i have now, into one js file?

Comment: @rishariss Not exactly, you can have two files as you are already having, I am just suggesting to wrap you code inside the `document.ready` function and that is because to register the custom event for the DOM manipulation

Comment: I tried wrapping both js files as you suggested but it had no effect. :/ I also edited first post according to ur suggestion.

Comment: Yes i did, no effect.

Comment: One more thing: If you declare a variable without using the var keyword, that variable is automically made global. So can you once try removing `var` from `menu` variable

Comment: Wow amazing, removing var from menu variable solved everything! Thank you so much! I also updated first post to working solution.

Comment: @rishariss You are welcome!!

Comment: @rishariss please don't edit the question as the another users visiting here may not found the problem, so it would be good if you revert your question back to original as it may be helpul for other person looking for same problem

Comment: You are correct, i reverted the question back to original, thanks again for ur help.

Answer (score 8):

[Managing javascript in drupal](https://drupal.org/node/756722)

As per the above link you should put your Javascript or Jquery inside the following :

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
   // add your code here
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.