# Custom Javascript doesnt work unless JQuery is set to Default jQuery Version

Tags: javascript

I spent the entire day trying to figure out why my custom JavaScript was not working.

Eventually I stumbled into the JQuery Update configuration and set it so that the JQuery that I use for my site was the "default (provided by Drupal)" setting and then it worked. Before it was set to 1.7 jQuery version. Looks like someone set it to 1.7 perhaps for magnific.js because that is now spitting out errors in my console "TypeError: a.off is not a function." Not sure what we use that js file for, but I find it strange that I never found anything on line about this being a potential issue when I was trying to troubleshoot my custom javascript.

Does anyone know anything about this? or am I just in left field? I know it wasn't the same issue the gentleman had in this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89501/custom-jquery-code-loaded-but-not-working.).

My custom code was not complex and it never worked. So I reduced it all down to just console out a simple message. But that proved to not work either. My simple console out code for my `pulsing.js` is:  `(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.notWorking = {
    attach: function () {
      console.log("finally is working");
    }
  };
}(jQuery));`

Ill just show the screen shots. The first one is the image where my custom code doesnt work because of jQuery update settings as I said above. [image]

The second one is what makes my custom code actually work - but like I said magnify.js then breaks - which maybe i'll hack at it or look for a newer version or something. [image]

Comment: This is not technically a Drupal question. Your custom code is not compatible with the jQuery version on the site.

Comment: If what your saying is true, then none of my custom javascript code, which was wrapped up with the `Drupal.behaviors`... boilerplate code, works for any jQuery version but that which comes straight out of Drupal's box. jQuery 1.5, 1.7, none of them worked. So it sounds like the answer is do not use any other jQuery version when coding for Drupal than the one that comes straight out of the box?

Comment: My code was a simple: `(function ($) {                                                      
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // Code to be run on page load, and
      console.log("hello");
    }
  };
}(jQuery));`

Comment: I sure didn't say that. You must code in the context of the libraries you have.

Comment: Is that *all* the code?

Comment: FYI Drupal.behaviors doesn't provide any special jQuery integration. It just helps load your code. Your code still must be compatible with jQuery and any other libraries on the page.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code; comments are not for giving important information like that. Also, provide your real code; I find a bit strange that all your custom code does is calling `console.log("hello")`.

Comment: Absolutely. First thing i do tomorrow morning when i get to work is post it all. Id rather not select the option jquery is on in development  for production if magnify.js is going to throw errors.

Comment: I hear you cilefen and thats good to know. I just post javascript code into console and i can get alert, when i wrap it in the drupal boilerplate i dont get the alert i was getting the console spit out the function. Thats why i thought that boilerplate was an issue. Ill post it all tomorrow morning

Answer (score 0):

magnific.js clearly needs the .off() function which was [added in jQuery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/off/). If you need magnific.js, you will need jQuery 1.7 and it is your job to upgraded your custom JavaScript accordingly.

- [Upgrade to 1.6](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/)
- [Upgrade to 1.7](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/)

You may find the changes you need are minimal.

Comment: That literally was all I was trying to do. All day. And the only thing that changed it was my solution in my question.

Comment: Maybe if you start from the standpoint of what errors are thrown by your custom code in 1.7?

Comment: There were no errors. For that file